# Error after migration to latest firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Please help. After upgrading the latest cloud_firestore, I have an error on this code:

```
  factory Question.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    Map data = snapshot.data()!;
```

error:

> A value of type 'Object' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'.

I have tried to check the migration [document](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/2.0.0_migration/) but I can't make it to work.

what I have tried:

```
factory Question.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>() snapshot) {
    Map data = snapshot.data()!;
```

update which seems to work:

```
factory Question.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
    Map data = snapshot.data()!;
```

Comment: Try with `Map<String, dynamic>` ?

Comment: The code you shared so far seems unmodified for version 2.0 of the plugin. Can you show what you tried from the documentation you linked?

Comment: I have added what I have tried

Comment: I think I have manage to update it correctly. I'm going to test it. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: can u share what your data looks like?

Comment: For now, it seems it working as per expected. Thanks to your reply. It made me realize what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to solve my issue:

```
factory Question.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
    Map data = snapshot.data()!;
```

Thanks to @Rishabh Deep Singh